# Aggregate with multiple return values: expand embedded matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, aggregate

When `aggregate`-ing a data.frame, and the function returns multiple values, these are stored in a matrix *within* one data.frame column (called "nested structure" or something). I want to expand these to be individual columns.

**MWE**

```
n = 10
df = data.frame(
  x = runif(n),
  g = sample(c('A','B'),n,rep=TRUE))

x.a = aggregate(x~g,df,quantile,probs=c(.025,.5,.975))
print(x.a)
print(names(x.a))
```

output:

```
  g    x.2.5%     x.50%   x.97.5%
1 A 0.2835977 0.8182352 0.9466469
2 B 0.5186207 0.8055592 0.9741885
[1] "g" "x" # want: "g" "x.2.5%" "x.50%" "x.97.5%"
```

If the data are all numeric, we can do

```
x.a = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,x.a))
```

but this converts factors to numeric.

EDIT: solution must be base R.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```r
df <- cbind(x.a[1], as.data.frame(x.a[[2]]))
```

This actually fixes the column names:

```r
df
#>   g      2.5%       50%     97.5%
#> 1 A 0.1342485 0.6285332 0.9230709
#> 2 B 0.1815917 0.2816160 0.3816404
```

And it is a proper data frame with four individual (non-matrix) columns:

```r
class(df)
#> [1] "data.frame"

names(df)
#> [1] "g"     "2.5%"  "50%"   "97.5%"
```

And the type of each column is correct:

```r
sapply(df, class)
#>           g        2.5%         50%       97.5% 
#> "character"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"
```

If you really want to keep the `x.` prefix in front of the percentages, an alternative would be:

```r
as.data.frame(c(x.a[1], asplit(x.a[2], 2)), check.names = FALSE)
#>   g    x.2.5%     x.50%   x.97.5%
#> 1 A 0.1342485 0.6285332 0.9230709
#> 2 B 0.1815917 0.2816160 0.3816404
```

This is also a four-column data frame with the correct types.